# Load data from *.xlsx or *.xls to Oracle table from Oracle Apex 4.0.2 User account

Tags: excel, oracle, csv, file-upload, oracle-apex

I need some help loading data from Excel Files (***.xlsx, *.xls**)to Oracle 11 using an Oracle Apex 4.0.2 User Account.

I found and modified a process to load *.cvs files. This process works as follows:

1. Load the ***.csv** files into a *BLOB* column.
2. After insert into the table, I execute the [image: Process]
3. This process inserts every row to the table

I want you to help me to code a similar code, but instead of loading *.csv I want it to work with Excel files.

`Oracle Apex 4.0.2` has a `Workshop` to load but it is only allowed to `Developers`, and I want to create this process in order to allow `Users` to load data by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great package developed by [Anton Scheffer](https://technology.amis.nl/author/anton-scheffer/) that allows you to work with xls or xlsx files (once uploaded as blobs) as tables and perform query operations like:

```
-- every sheet and every cell
    select *
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ) ) )
--
-- cell A3 from the first and the second sheet
    select *
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ), '1:2', 'A3' ) )
--
-- every cell from the sheet with the name "Sheet3"
    select *
    from table( as_read_xlsx.read( as_read_xlsx.file2blob( 'DOC', 'Book1.xlsx' ), 'Sheet3' ) )
```

Then you could use the data as needed.

[Here's the code](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/as_read_xlsx9.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you don't upgrade to apex 5.0, or at the very least 4.2? The "Data Loading" components have been added in 4.1 and offer you a fast way of developing this exact requirement. 4.0 is ancient by now and no longer supported.

Loading an xlsx or xls is vastly, vastly different from loading a CSV. Again, I'd ask, why not update. There are plugins available which process excel files to collections, even XLSX. Again though, your apex version is too low. **You're shooting yourself in the foot her**e. Not that there aren't coding options available, but still.

If you **still** don't want to upgrade for some arbitrary reason, focus perhaps on xlsx files. They're essentially zip-files with a bunch of files. I wrote a blog on this back in 2012. http://tpetrus.blogspot.be/2012/09/a-non-standard-export-to-excel-2010-xlsx.html

It's still relevant and I'm only linking it because it contains all the guts of the code. It's not infallible and has limits though. There's probably other ways, too. Less so for 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. someday's ago I done something like this.
I was upload some Excel Files (*.xlsx, *.xls) in oracle database table using oracle apex by a Apex plugin call "Excel2collection".
Actually first I was load the excel file into apex collection table then I move it from collection to oracle database.
Here I provide a link of my blog where I write the full process step by step.
[Link: qaiumer.blogspot.com](https://qaiumer.blogspot.com/2017/10/pload-excel-file-into-apex-collection.html)

Comment: Answers pointing towards a link are much appreciated if you could post the relevant codes along with it, as links may die with time!

Answer (score -1):

Excel2Collection plugin is hard to beat. That's Anton's solution bundled into an APEX plugin. This way you can feed the file browse item into a process and have it spit out APEX Collection records

Demo:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=52007:6:::NO:::

Plugin:
http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/process-type-plugin/excel2collections_271.html

Comment: why the downvote? It accepts *.xls, *.xlsx, multiple worksheets are handled, a demo was provided... The only constraint is 50 columns, but that can be overcome.