# How do you import data from your excel spreadsheet to ORACLE APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am completely new to databases, was wondering if there were ways to direcly upload the data in an excel file, to ORACLE APEX, if not, what would the best way be to upload small datasets .CSV extension around 15MB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load data from \*.xlsx or \*.xls to Oracle table from Oracle Apex 4.0.2 User account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645697/load-data-from-xlsx-or-xls-to-oracle-table-from-oracle-apex-4-0-2-user-accou)

Answer (score 3):

Apex enables you to directly upload CSV files using the Data Load Wizard. You can find a lot of tutorials. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r41/dataload/dataload.htm#t3) is just one.

You can also upload Excel files using the following methods:

- [EXCEL2COLLECTIONS Plugin](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/process-type-plugin/excel2collections_271.html)
- Create a procedure that will translate excel data into strings. [Tutorial here.](https://avdeo.com/2008/05/21/uploading-excel-sheet-using-oracle-application-express-apex/)
- Using AS_READ_XLSX package. [Tutorial here.](http://pretius.com/how-to-create-report-from-xlsx-file-in-oracle-apex/)

Don't be shy to use google because you will find many more options.