# How to choose Storage Type is WWV_FLOW_FILES in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created a page and want to import the excel file in Oracle APEX, but when I select Storage type to Save temp data then I can't see table **WWV_FLOW_FILES**, so how can I look for it???

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you want to do with the spreadsheet - load the data into a database or process the file after it is uploaded. Also, always indicate software version.

Have you seen this: http://dba-oracle.com/t_easy_html_db_storing_files_in_html_db.htm  and https://www.foxinfotech.in/2013/05/importing-files-in-oracle-apex-using-wwv_flow_files.html

Have you read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/understanding-blob-support-in-forms.htm#HTMDB30075)?

```
> There are two different types of storage types available within the
> File Browse item type:
> 
>     BLOB column specific in Item Source Attribute - Completely declarative approach that supports configuration of the additional
> settings discussed here. This references a BLOB in your own database
> table.
> 
>     Table WWV_FLOW_FILES - Available for backwards compatibility. Oracle does not recommend using this in new applications.

Table APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES - Store the uploaded file in a temporary location that you can access with the view APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES. Oracle Application Express automatically deletes the file at the end of the session or at the end of the upload request, depending on what you choose for Purge File At.
```

**Note:** The intent is you upload the file then process it with PL/SQL after it is uploaded. Access it from the view: APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES

Or other tutorials on the web, like: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/08/file-upload-improvements-in-apex-5-1/   basically the file upload is to a temporary table for further processing after the upload. 
Other links:[How do you import data from your excel spreadsheet to ORACLE APEX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149052/how-do-you-import-data-from-your-excel-spreadsheet-to-oracle-apex), https://community.oracle.com/thread/1022147

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much about your answer.